# Why my Array find function doesn't work properly even I did the same thing document

Tags: arrays, reactjs, find

So something is wrong with my code but I don't get it where is the wrong..so basically I want to find my items that I registered in my account..
Basically like this code.

```
const evergreens = [
  { name: "cedar", count: 2 },
  { name: "fir", count: 6 },
  { name: "pine", count: 3 }
];

// suppose we need to skip the first element
const result = evergreens.find((tree, i) => {
  if (tree.count > 1 && i !== 0) return true;
});
```

That is what i saw in this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-array-find-method)

And when I tried to get my data in backend it doesn't work.. this is the code..

```
const [name,setname] = useState()
  const [password,setpassword] = useState()
  const [key,setkey] = useState()
  
  const [option,setoption] = useState("Register")

  const [list,setlist] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:7171/users/')
        .then(list => setlist(list.data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
        // console.log(list)
  },[])

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    
    e.preventDefault()

    const Inputs = {key:key, name:name, password:password}

    if (option == "Register") {
      console.log(list)

      // this shows the list of the data []

      const findItem = list.find((data,i) => 
        data.name === name
      )
      //but this one doesn't work I don't understand how I just did the same thing though..

      console.log(findItem)
      //This one will gives an undefined value

      // Register(Inputs)
      
      setname("")
      
      setpassword("")
      
      setkey("")

    }
  
  }
```

Does anything I haven't applied here or is there just an error with my codes? I believe I didn't skip anything at here.. I don't understand this thing how it shows an undefined value.

**EDITED**

`(2) [{…}, {…}] 0: {_id: '6232ac00ae5cf39abb58febd', name: 'Hahahatdog', password: '123123123', key: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP', createdAt: '2022-03-17T03:33:20.809Z', …} 1: {_id: '6232ac14ae5cf39abb58fec0', name: 'cutekabatdog', password: '123123123', key: 'nakoiyakKLMNOP', createdAt: '2022-03-17T03:33:40.339Z', …} length: 2 [[Prototype]]: Array(0)`

Comment: When you `console.log(list)`, do it show the list of items or just an empty array `[]`? Can you share what is logged to the console?

Comment: here you go bro..

Comment: yes it show the list but cannot find anything.

Comment: Can you try a console log for the variable `name` as well?

Comment: Do you want me to show all the codes and try it in your terminal ?

Comment: oh wait imma try.

Comment: if I try `console.log(list[0].name]) ` it will show the name though..

Comment: Yes, but I'm wondering if the variable name (that the user inputs I guess) has a value when you do the find. So just `console.log(name)`

Comment: Yes, it does working though...

Comment: That's weird then, I can take a look at your code and try it myself if you don't mind sharing it

Comment: I did try to position my `const findItem` into my useEffect... but still it doesn't work though...

Comment: How can I share it to you??

Comment: You can use [CodePen](https://codepen.io/topic/react/templates) with a React template if you want, or maybe just as plain text on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)

Comment: Wait wait...just wait huhuh this is literally super weird haha...imma post in in my codepen.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-haze-3sbw1k?file=/backend/model/user-model.js

Comment: here bro help me hahaha..

Comment: Have you find the issue sir?

Comment: Yes, I have shared a solution to your issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code shared [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-haze-3sbw1k?file=/src/UsersAndMainPeople/User.jsx), it seems that the issue comes from the input fields not updating the state properly. Your code for that is:

```
<input
  type="text"
  className="form-group-input"
  name="name"
  onChange={(e) => setname(e)}
/>
```

And that results in assigning the event (`e`) itself in the state, rather than the value, which is in `e.target.value`. So doing this should resolve your issue. Additionally, I would advise adding `value={name}` as a prop to the input to make the input controlled, thus clearing it when you submit the form. This would result in:

```
<input
  type="text"
  className="form-group-input"
  name="name"
  onChange={(e) => setname(e.target.value)}
  value={name}
/>
```

You can read more on controlled components in React [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).